# Inequality $\sqrt{(a+1)^2+b^2} \leq (a+1)^2+b^2 + \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Tags: inequality

I am looking for a high school level proof of the following inequality for real numbers $a,b$:
$$ \sqrt{(a+1)^2+b^2} \leq (a+1)^2+b^2 + \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It seems to me it should follow fairly directly from squaring the LHS and adding $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: what kind of numbers are $a,b$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(-1,0), B(0,0), C(a,b)$. Then we have that $AB = 1$, $AC = \sqrt{(a+1)^2 + b^2}$, $AB =  \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Then the inequality transforms to:

$$AC \le AC^2 + AB$$

If $AC\ge 1$, then the inequality is obviously true. Now assume $AC < 1$. Then using the Triangle inequality we have:

$$AC^2 + AB \ge AC^2 + |AC-1| = AC^2 + 1 - AC \ge AC$$

Where the last inequality comes from $(AC - 1)^2 \ge 0$. Obviously we have equality when $AC = 1$ and $A\equiv C$, i.e. $a=b=0$